# Why does an ICommand object have to be public to work properly in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am following a course on **Pluralsight** called "**Practical MVVM**". In the 4th module of the course, the author was explaining how to use **commands** and that's when I had this strange issue. I had written almost the same code as it was in the video except for one difference. My local `ICommand` variable was declared as `private` instead of `public`.

Here is what happens when I click the button that has a Binding set to the method `EditCoffee()` that belongs to `EditCommand` command:

- When `ICommand EditCommand` is declared as **public** or **internal** the method `EditCoffee()` is executed following the execution of `Execute()` and `CanExecute()` in `CustomCommand` class.
- When `ICommand EditCommand` is declared as **private** or **protected** the method `EditCoffee()` is never executed and does not follow execution of `Execute()` and `CanExecute()` in `CustomCommand` class.

It's worth mentioning that `LoadCommands()` is triggered on in both scenarios.

**CoffeeOverviewViewModel:**

```
using JoeCoffeeStore.StockManagement.App.Services;
using JoeCoffeeStore.StockManagement.App.Utility;
using JoeCoffeeStore.StockManagement.Model;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace JoeCoffeeStore.StockManagement.App.ViewModel
{
    public class CoffeeOverviewViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation   
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }      

        // Commands   
        private ICommand EditCommand { get; set; }           

        // Data Service
        private CoffeeDataService _coffeeDataService;

        // Properties
        private ObservableCollection<Coffee> _coffees;    
        public ObservableCollection<Coffee> Coffees
        {
            get{ return _coffees; }
            set
            {
                _coffees = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private Coffee _selectedCoffee;    
        public Coffee SelectedCoffee
        {
            get { return _selectedCoffee; }
            set
            {
                _selectedCoffee = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        // Constructor
        public CoffeeOverviewViewModel()
        {
            _coffeeDataService = new CoffeeDataService();
            LoadData();    
            LoadCommands();
        }


        private void LoadCommands()
        {
            EditCommand = new CustomCommand(EditCoffee, CanEditCoffee);
        }

        private void EditCoffee(object obj)
        {                
            //TODO
        }

        private bool CanEditCoffee(object obj)
        {
            if (SelectedCoffee != null)
                return true;
            return false;    
        }

        private void LoadData()
        {
            Coffees = new ObservableCollection<Coffee>(_coffeeDataService.GetAllCoffees());
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomCommand.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace JoeCoffeeStore.StockManagement.App.Utility
{
    public class CustomCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> _execute;
        private Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        public CustomCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            bool b = _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
            return b;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

**CoffeeOverviewView.xaml:**

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="7">
    <Button  Command="{Binding EditCommand}" Content="Edit coffee"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Solution structure:**

[image]

Comment: It has nothing to with commands specifically, this applies to all bindings in WPF. Any property you want to bind to *must* be public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binding isn't magic. It's code that takes your XAML binding declaration:

```
 <Button  Command="{Binding EditCommand}"
```

and looks for a property of that name, `EditCommand`, in the DataContext of your class.

Your XAML view is a separate class than your ViewModel, so it makes sense that it can only access public properties on the ViewModel. Even internal properties are out of bounds, because it's the *binding* code that tries to access it, in the WPF libraries, not your own view code.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I got so used to things "just working" that I forgot about the relationship of XAML and classes. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: @Clemens True, I was confused by the OP stating in the question that internal Commands worked. Fixed.